# How to add from sqlite database into a for loop

Tags: java, android, sqlite, for-loop, listview

So im trying to get 3 of my columns from my database from sqlite to be put into my arraylist then displayed into a list view but at the moment it is only displaying the quantity. Eg: Name: 1  Quantity: 1  Type: 1
But I want it to display all of the other columns instead of just the quantity so the output would actually be: Name: Milk  Quantity: 1  Type: Ingredient
Does anyone know how to do this?

InventoryStatus class:

```
public class InventoryStatus extends AppCompatActivity {
DatabaseHelper myDB;
int currentPosition = 0;

private ArrayList<String> fullList;
private ArrayList<String> displayedList;
ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter;
ListView listView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_inventory_status);

    listView = findViewById(R.id.listViewStock);
    Button btNext = findViewById(R.id.buttonNext);
    Button btPrevious = findViewById(R.id.buttonPrevious);

    myDB = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    Cursor data = myDB.getAllData();

    fullList = new ArrayList<>();
    displayedList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        fullList.add("Name: " + i + "Quantity: " + i + "Type: " + i);
    }

    if (fullList.size() == 0)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No data found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else // fullList isn't empty show first 5 items in ListView
    {
        setDisplayListPosition();
        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    }

    btNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) // change current position and refresh ListView
        {
            currentPosition += 5;
            if (currentPosition > fullList.size()) currentPosition -= 5;
            else
                setDisplayListPosition();
        }
    });

    btPrevious.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() // change current position and refresh ListView
    {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            currentPosition -= 5;
            if (currentPosition < 0) currentPosition = 0;
            else
                setDisplayListPosition();
        }
    });

}

private void setDisplayListPosition() // helper function which refresh ListView based on `currentPos`
{
    displayedList.clear();

    for (int i = 0; i < 5 && i + currentPosition < fullList.size(); i++) {
        displayedList.add(fullList.get(currentPosition + i)); // ad 5 items from finalList to displayedList
    }

    listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            displayedList
    );

}
}
```

DatabaseHelper class:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Inventory.db";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Inventory_table";
public static final String COL1 = "ID";
public static final String COL2 = "Name";
public static final String COL3 = "Quantity";
public static final String COL4 = "Type";


public  DatabaseHelper(Context context){
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
}


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    String createTable = "create table " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + " Name TEXT, Quantity Text, Type Text)";
    db.execSQL(createTable);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {

    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}
public boolean insertData(String Name, String Quantity, String Type){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL2, Name);
    contentValues.put(COL3, Quantity);
    contentValues.put(COL4, Type);
    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

    if(result == -1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;

}

// Gets all data
public Cursor getAllData(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor data = db.rawQuery("select * from " + TABLE_NAME, null);
    return data;
}

// Deletes all data
public String deletedata(){
    SQLiteDatabase myDB = this.getWritableDatabase();
    myDB.delete(TABLE_NAME, null, null);
    myDB.close();

    return null;
}
}
```

Comment: What's the host language? Java? Possibly for Android? [Edit]  the question and add the appropriate tags.

Comment: Yes its java in android studio sorry @stickybit

Answer (score 0):

Change this :

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        fullList.add("Name: " + i + "Quantity: " + i + "Type: " + i);
    }
```

to :

```
if(cursor.moveToFirst())
    for(int i=0; i<5 ;i++){   
          fullList.add("Name: " + cursor.getString(1) + "Quantity: " + cursor.getString(2) + "Type: " + cursor.getString(3));
          if(!cursor.moveToNext())
               break;
   }
```

Comment: Hi @Anasxon I tried your code but now when i go onto this activity the app just shuts off. Do you know of any other way to go about this?

Comment: @HarryBrown I also tried this code, but I had no such problem. Maybe there is a bug elsewhere